# How to add custom header in ajax request using plain javascript (NOT JQUERY)?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please could someone advise on how to add a header to an AJAX request using plain javascript?  I am trying to upload a video file to a server and want to let it know the file size and type of the file I am sending.
 I found someone solutions but this involved jQUERY which is not what I am after.

For example:

```
  Content-Length: 339108
  Content-Type: video/mp4
```

My AJAX request:

```
 var startUpload = function(){
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('requestUpload', 'uploadTicket');

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
                var response = xmlhttp.responseText;

                if(response == '1'){

                    document.getElementById('UploadBox').innerHTML = '<div id="upWrap"><input type="file" id="vidInput"><button id="submitFile" onclick="">Upload Video<button></div>';

                }
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open('POST', 'myFile.php');
        xmlhttp.send(formdata);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [setRequestHeader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader) method of XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Length', '339108')
```

Comment: You must call it after calling open()

Answer (score 2):

You must call it after calling `open()`, but before calling `send()`

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*');
```

And not all headers canbe set, refer this
**[Forbidden_header_name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Forbidden_header_name)**

**Tip:**
Server side should Also support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`